# Tomcat is not working properly in Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9

Apache Tomcat is not working in my PC. I have uninstalled Eclipse, JRE and Tomcat sevaral times. But i can't figure what happened and it's always showing like below.

"
could not load the tomcat server configuration at c:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 9.0\conf. the configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.

Reason:Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at C:\Program FIles\Apache Software FOundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete

<<Details
cp65001
"
Help me to figure out what's happened. I've tried several solutions in Stack Overflow. But not working.

Answer (score 1):

As the [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F) says, don't use an installed copy. In the case of Windows, *especially* don't use an installed copy under the "Program Files" directories. Permission management there is always something of a nightmare. Download a .zip from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi and use that instead, preferably from a location your user has full ownership of.

Comment: But when i enter the localhost in the browser,
 
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.38

Comment: Unless you deploy an application with the context "ROOT", that's expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that those file actually exist on that path?